# Как я могу вывести данные из API?

Tags: python, json

Я использую requests и json для извлечения данных из API. Мне необходимо вывести только "name" из раздела "data" и все маркет пары из того же раздела, но вывести вместе с "exchange name", "market URL", "price" и "last update".Я не знаю, как я могу это сделать. Пожалуйста, дайте мне руку помощи.

API:
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/market-pairs/latest?slug=klima-dao&start=1&limit=100&category=spot&sort=cmc_rank_advanced

Мой код:

```
response = s.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()

        json_data = response['data']
        find_name_of_coin = json_data['name']
        find_marketPairs = json_data['numMarketPairs']
        find_info_marketPairs = json_data['marketPairs']
        Market_pairs = find_marketPairs['exchangeName']['marketUrl'['price']

        print('info: ' f"{'name_of_Coin: ' + find_name_of_coin + ' ' + 'market_Pairs: ' + str(find_marketPairs) + ' ' + Market_pairs}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам рабочий код, немного переделанный из вашего:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/market-pairs/latest?slug=klima-dao&start=1&limit=100&category=spot&sort=cmc_rank_advanced"

response = requests.get(url=url).json()

json_data = response['data']
find_name_of_coin = json_data['name']
find_marketPairs = json_data['numMarketPairs']
find_info_marketPairs = json_data['marketPairs']

print(f"{'name_of_Coin: ' + find_name_of_coin + ' ' + 'market_Pairs: ' + str(find_marketPairs) + ' ' + Market_pairs}")

for info in find_info_marketPairs:
    print(f"{info['exchangeName']} {info['marketUrl']} {info['price']} {info['lastUpdated']}")
```

Вывод:

```
name_of_Coin: Klima DAO market_Pairs: 6 
Sushiswap(Polygon) https://app.sushi.com/ 638.5962343082055 2021-12-03T12:24:11.000Z
Sushiswap(Polygon) https://app.sushi.com/ 638.5962343082055 2021-12-03T12:24:11.000Z
Sushiswap(Polygon) https://app.sushi.com/ 638.5962343082055 2021-12-03T12:24:11.000Z
Sushiswap(Polygon) https://app.sushi.com/ 639.3481349583593 2021-12-03T12:24:11.000Z
Hotbit https://www.hotbit.io/exchange?symbol=KLIMA_USDT 644.9775003426461 2021-12-03T12:24:12.000Z
Sushiswap(Polygon) https://app.sushi.com/ 653.8933202472447 2021-12-03T12:24:11.000Z
```

Как доставать инфу я вам показал, а более красиво вывод вы сами причешите тогда.